# Lower bounds in the space of compact operators

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space, and $K(H)$ the corresponding space of compact operators. Consider the "unit sphere" $S:=\{T\in K(H)|T\geq 0\text{ and }||T||=1\}$. Is it true that, given any pair of operators $T_1,T_2\in S$, there exists another operator $T\in S$ such that $T\leq T_1,T_2$?.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! What if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are orthogonal projections with product $0$?

Comment: Jochen's counterexample works of course for $\dim H =2$ ...